# Calling class constructor inside another class using a pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to initialize an object of a class inside a member function of another class. The problem is that I need to pass a function pointer to the constructor. I do not know how I can make this. This is the error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘inheritance01::inheritance01(double (inheritance02::*&)(double))’
     inheritance01 LT (func);
```

The code below shows the problem.

```
class Base01 {
public:
    Base01(double (*)(double));
    virtual double calc(double) = 0;
    double (*ptr_fd() const)(double) { return ptr_fd_; }
private:
    double (*ptr_fd_)(double);
};

Base01::Base01(double (*f)(double))
    : ptr_fd_(f)
{
}
//----------------------------------------------------
class inheritance01 : public Base01 {
public:
    inheritance01(double (*ptr_f)(double));
    virtual double calc(double);
};

inheritance01::inheritance01(double (*pf)(double))
    : Base01(pf)
{
}

double inheritance01::calc(double t) { return 2.0 * t; }
//###################################################

class Base02 {
public:
    Base02(double);
    virtual double solution(double, double) = 0;
    double a() { return a_; };
private:
    const double a_;
};
Base02::Base02(double aa)
    : a_(aa)
{
}
//------------------------------------------------------
class inheritance02 : public Base02 {
public:
    inheritance02(double, double);
    virtual double solution(double, double);
    //static double sol_aux (double);
private:
    double sol_aux(double);
    const double b;
    //double (inheritance02::*fptrsol_aux)(double u) = &inheritance02::sol_aux;
    typedef double (inheritance02::*fptr)(double u);
    fptr func;
};

inheritance02::inheritance02(double aa, double bb)
    : Base02(aa)
    , b(bb)
{
    //func = double (*sol_aux)(double);
    //func = &inheritance02::sol_aux;
}
//--------------------------------------------------
double inheritance02::sol_aux(double u)
{
    return (a() + b) / u;
}
//--------------------------------------------------
double inheritance02::solution(double x, double t)
{
    //inheritance01 LT (&func);
    //inheritance01 LT (this->func);
    //inheritance01 LT (&fptrsol_aux);
    inheritance01 LT(func); // Here is the problem
    return LT.calc(x + t);
}
//########################################################
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    inheritance02 obj(1.0, 1.0);
    double value = obj.solution(1.0, 1.0);
    std::cout << "value = " << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef double (inheritance02::*fptr)(double u);` should be `typedef double (*fptr)(double u);`

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by @Eljay says, you are creating a typedef for a pointer to member function here:

```
typedef double (inheritance02::*fptr)(double u);
```

However, the constructor of `inheritance01` takes a regular function pointer as an argument:

```
inheritance01( double (*ptr_f)(double));
```

so this line:

```
inheritance01 LT(func); // Here is the problem
```

doesn't work because the types don't match up (pointer to member functions are not convertible to function pointers).

The easy fix would be to make `func` a regular function pointer, like this:

```
typedef double (*fptr)(double u);
```

and everything should work fine.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/_zk7bu).

Comment: Hello cigien and @Eljay, many thanks for the answer.  It's work fine.

However, when I replace (line 28) "double inheritance01::calc(double t) { return 2.0*t;}" by "double inheritance01::calc(double t) { return Base01::ptr_fd()( 2.0*t);}" I receive segmentation fault error. Could you help me?

Comment: You never initialize `func` in the constructor of `Base02`, so `Base01::pf` is dangling, so invoking `Base01::ptr_fd` is UB.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not able to declare the 'func_' parameter as const and private (I do not know how to return a std::function) the following code solves my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
class Base01
{
public:
    Base01( std::function<double (double)> );
    virtual double calc( double ) = 0;
    //function<double (double)> func { return func_; }
    function<double (double)> func;
private:
    //const function<double (double)> func_;   
};
Base01::Base01( function<double (double)> f) : func(f) {}
//----------------------------------------------------
class inheritance01:public Base01
{
public:
    inheritance01( function<double (double)> );
    virtual double calc( double ); 
};

inheritance01::inheritance01 (function<double (double)> f): Base01(f){}

double inheritance01::calc(double t) { return Base01::func(2.0*t); }
//###################################################
class Base02
{
public:
Base02(double);   
virtual double solution(double, double) = 0;
double a(){return a_;};
private:
const double a_;
};
Base02::Base02(double aa): a_(aa) {}
//------------------------------------------------------
class inheritance02 : public Base02
{
public:
    inheritance02( double, double );    
    virtual double solution(double, double);   
private:
    double sol_aux (double);
    const double b;
}; 

inheritance02::inheritance02 (double aa, double bb) 
: Base02(aa), b(bb)
{}
//--------------------------------------------------
double inheritance02::sol_aux(double u) { return (a()+b)/u; }
//--------------------------------------------------
double inheritance02::solution(double x, double y)
{
inheritance01 LT ( bind( &inheritance02::sol_aux, this, placeholders::_1) );
return LT.calc(x+y);
}
//########################################################
int main()
{
inheritance02 obj (1.0,1.0);
double value = obj.solution(1.0,1.0);
std::cout << "value = " << value << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```